# Foreach label get id - modify this id - add to parent class

Tags: jquery, foreach

I am trying to make a universal code that can be used in every module for the Joomla CMS Backend. The code needs to grab the ID from the labels and add this id as a class to the nearest parent with the class `control-group`

## Basic build up of a Joomla Module:

```
<div class="control-group">
  <div class="control-label">
    <label id="jform_params_some_text_here-lbl" for="jform_params_some_text_here" class="hasPopover"></label>
  </div>
  <div class="controls"></div>
</div>
```

## What is the best way to do this universally

I know that I can set it individual with this:

```
 (function ($) {
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#jform_params_some_text_here-lbl").parents(".control-group").addClass("jform_params_some_text_here-cg");
   });
 })(jQuery);
```

But I need to have it universal.

## What do I want to achieve

1. Foreach label get the id.
2. Remove the letters `lbl` and replace with the letters `cg`
3. Find nearest parent with class `control-group`
4. Add the just renamed class to this parent

## Thanks to everyone for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of jQuery's available [has attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) to only target label elements with a defined `id` attribute to avoid any undefined errors.

You should then be able to see your preferred steps annotated below :

```
// Step 1: Iterate through each label that has an `id` attribute
$('label[id]').each(function(){
     // Step 2: Get your replacement id
     var id = $(this).attr('id').replace('lbl','cg');
     // Step 3: Find your nearest parent with "control-group" class
     var parent = $(this).parents('.control-group');
     // Step 4: Now set the class for your parent element
     parent.addClass(id);
});
```