# for each ID remove three letters and add two letters

Tags: jquery, replace, each

I am grabbing the ID from all labels on a page. I know want to remove three letters from it and replace those with two letters.

I got the following:

```
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('label').each(function(index) {
      var id = $(this).attr('id');
      var idm = id.replace('lbl','cg')
      $(this).parents('.control-group').addClass(idm);
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

But I get the error `Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined`

In my first try I written it like this but got the same error:

```
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('label').each(function(index) {
      var id = $(this).attr('id').replace('lbl','cg');
      $(this).parents('.control-group').addClass(id);
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Do _all_ of the labels have an id?

Comment: Don't know as it is universal therefore I chose to go with the answer from Rion as it checks for all labels with a id and then executes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I get the error Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

This is likely because one of your `<label>` elements did not have an `id` attribute defined.

You might consider only targeting `<label>` elements that you already know have an `id` attribute as seen below using [the has attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) :

```
// Only target a label with a defined id attribute
$('label[id]').each(function(index) {
   var id = $(this).attr('id').replace('lbl','cg');
   $(this).parents('.control-group').addClass(id);
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this it works like a charm. I can accept in 10 minutes.

Comment: So I asked another question about 20 minutes ago and it is related to this one. Actually the code you give here is the exact code needed for that question. Should I delete the other question (while it is a different question) or can you post this answer also there? Or should I post it?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42076925/foreach-label-get-id-modify-this-id-add-to-parent-class

I have posted a link to this question in the meanwhile.